# Trying to count each digit in an item in a list (beginner Python)

Tags: python, list, loops, integer

Trying to find out how to count each character in an item in a list, not count the items in the list only. I am not checking for a subtstring in a list of items, and the only related question does not answer mine.

Hitting a wall, with some messy code trying to apply what I learned from freecodecamp and 100 days of python to codewars but not sure what I'm doing wrong.
if someone could be kind enough to point out what I'm missing? I checked some solutions but wanted to do it the long way to understand each step.

For every digit in a range, I'd like to count them and return a list of each digit count.

```
def paint_letterboxes(start, finish):
    digitstocount = '0123456789'
    housenumbers = []
    for housenum in range(start, finish +1):
      housenumbers.append(str(housenum)) #make into a string to count each instance??
    print(housenumbers)    
    counteddigits = [housenumbers.count(digit) for digit in digitstocount]
    print(counteddigits)

paint_letterboxes(125,132)
```

the output i'm getting is:

```
['125', '126', '127', '128', '129', '130', '131', '132']
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

intended output would be:

```
['125', '126', '127', '128', '129', '130', '131', '132']
[1,9,6,3,0,1,1,1,1,1]
```

because the digit 0 appears 1 time, 1 appears 9 times, 2 appears 6 times, etc.

Comment: `count` will count the number of times a digit occurs in your list, but *exactly*, not as a substring. Since your list has no single digits, you get all zeroes.

Comment: okay, if I add the all characters of this substring into an array and then remove the ' and spaces, would this work?

Comment: Either add all individual characters to a list, or don't create a list at all but one large string . But realise that this "brute force" algorithm might not be efficient enough for whoever gave you this challenge. Think of the memory needed to deal with `paint_letterboxes(125,9892155)`.